# Not able to extract keys from X509 certificate

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate

I am getting below exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe Additional information: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

What i am trying is below

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsacsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Certificate.PrivateKey;

pubkey.Key = rsacsp.ExportParameters(false);

privkey.Key = rsacsp.ExportParameters(true);
```

The exception is seen at  pubkey.Key = rsacsp.ExportParameters(false);

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey.aspx) says the PrivateKey property returns either an RSACryptoServiceProvider or a DSACryptoServiceProvider object.

Comment: @TestUser: Is `pubkey` `null`?

Comment: Is there a way to make the keys of an X509 certificate exportable. I am having an existing X509 certificate and i want it to initialise a copy of it with keys made as exportable. please guide.

Comment: thanks. my bad. pubkey was indeed null. initialised it and bingo.thanks to you all